# Jquery div transition based on unordered list

Tags: jquery, html, transition

I have a navbar on a page that looks like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Header 2</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Header 3</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
```

Where the navbar ends up like `| Home | Header 2 | Header 3|`

Now, when a user clicks on `Item 1` from home, it'd be nice for the div to use the page slide transition have the Item 1 div slide in from the right. Similarly, if the user were then to click on `Item 2`, the div would slide up from the bottom. Again, if they were to click on `Home`, the div would slide in from the left.
I guess what I want is the page slide to come from teh same direction as the link is positioned relative to the current page. 
Is this possible and if so, what's the best way to implement it?

Comment: what you have tried so far? tried to google over it?

Comment: Please Post your sample code

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, it's purely speculative at this point. I've googled but come up with no sensible pages for what I want to (i.e. select transition based on where link is in an unordered list).